# Elasticsearch frequency of field pair

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been logging failed attempts to log-in to my servers into elasticsearch.

I want to now find the most common pairs of username and passwords attempts.

I have this for a single field, but how do i find the most frequently used username and password combinations?

Thanks

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "top-username-aggregation":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"username",
            "size":10
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another sub aggregation for password.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "top-user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "username",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top-passwords": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "password",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: glad I could help